# Calculate resolution of sprite texture in Pixi.js

Tags: javascript, webgl, pixi.js

How can i calculate the resolution of a generated texture in PIXI.js. The documentation of generateTexture(...) requires a number for the resolution.

Doc: http://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.Graphics.html#generateTexture

In the following example, a rectangle with a specific width and height will be drawn. The resolution would be the number of pixels through the multiplication of width and height in my opinion.

```
this._graphics.lineStyle(1, 0x012489, 1.0);
this._graphics.beginFill(0x696969, this.1.0);
this._graphics.drawRect(-(width/2.0), -(height/2.0), width, height);
this._graphics.endFill();

this.texture = this._graphics.generateTexture(width * height, PIXI.SCALE_MODES.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Your assumption sounds right, but i cant confirm it now. But you didnt seem to take into account the starting x and y coordinates. The size isnt only width * height, since you dont start at coordinates 0, 0. Also note that since graphics are vectors you can of course provide any resolution you want the image to have. It does not need to be exactly the same as in graphics, as it gets scaled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code it seems that what resolution sets, is not resolution, but the relative resolution, pratically this: https://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.BaseTexture.html#resolution, so as it states: "the resolution of the texture for devices with different pixel ratios".

The default is 1, which is normal for desktop devices, the pixel ratio can be different on mobile devices. You should be able to get pixel ratio with this function (getPixelRatio): https://github.com/Hachitus/FlaTWorld/blob/master/src/components/map/core/utils/utils.js#L195 , but the function is not really battle-tested, though hasn't shown any issues in tests so far either.